# Can't extend String prototype?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to extend the String class in Actionscript 3. My goal is to add tags around a string automatically.

Code:

```
String.prototype.addTags = function(t1:String, t2:String) : String {
    return t1 + this + t2;
}
```

And then calling the function:

```
var str:String = "hello";
str.addTags("<b>", "</b>");


// expected output: <b>hello</b>
trace(str);
```

This generates the following error:

*1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addTags through a reference with static type String.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with some of the other answers that consider this a "bad idea". However, just to answer your question, the problem with your original code is simply that you weren't doing anything with the returned value of `addTags()`. This should work:

```
String.prototype.addTags = function(t1:String, t2:String):String {
    return t1 + this + t2;
}

var str:String = "hello";
str = str.addTags("<b>", "</b>");

trace(str); // <b>hello</b>
```

Although in "strict mode" you'll get a compile error on `str.addTags()` because `addTags()` is not a known method of `String` by the compiler. You can get around this by using a dynamic reference or casting to `Object` which is dynamic:

```
str = Object(str).addTags("<b>", "</b>");
```

The `Array` class is already dynamic, so that's why you don't get this compile error when using methods added to the array prototype.

Again, I agree with others that there are "better" ways to do this. (ie ways that fit AS3's language design better.)

Comment: Thanks, the quarter finally dropped.. :) (about the difference between Array and String classes). I agree this might not be the best solution, I was just curious why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. And you cannot extend primitive types. Better will be if you create class-utility to do whatever you want. For example:

```
package {
    public class StringUtil {
        public static function addTags(value:String, leftTag:String, rightTag:String):String {
            return leftTag + value + rightTag;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. It's just example. There are many different ways to implement what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's how I'm implementing it now.  I always thought this was possible since there are many examples of people extending the Array class with prototype. Check this example: http://www.benjaminkeen.com/arrayprototypeshuffle-as3/

Comment: Array isn't a primitive type. Maybe it is a reason why it possible.

Comment: I believe in ActionScript String isn't a primitive datatype, it's a class, a reference type and cannot be extended because is final.

Comment: @gPeart Sorry, but I think you are wrong. According to docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f88.html

Comment: @Crabar, it's an interesting topic and deserve proper investigation :)
Thanks for pointing the official documentation!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that using "prototype", you can upcast your string (or number if you want) to an `Object` like this :

```
Object.prototype.addTags = function(t1:String, t2:String):String {
    return t1 + this + t2;
}

var str:String = 'hello';
    str = Object(str).addTags('<b>', '</b>');

trace(str);                                     // gives : <b>hello</b>

trace(Object('world').addTags('<u>', '</u>'));  // gives : <u>world</u>

trace(Object(2015).addTags('<p>', '</p>'));     // gives : <p>2015</p>
```

Hope that can help.